# excel vba giving a value to next variable in the same sub

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I have a sub where I get values every time I run it. What I would like to do, is to add a variable, to another each time the sub runs. For example, I have x, a, b, c variables inside the sub.

Lets say the sub runs 4 times and each time it runs, x gets the following values: 1. "5" 2. "2" 3. "7" 4. "11"

x gives the value forward to a. a, b, and c are writen into a cell, and the result should be | 5 | | - | | - |

at the second run, b should get the value of a and a should get the value of the new x. than we get the result: | 2 | | 5 | | - |

third run, we have a c as well: | 7 | | 2 | | 5 |

forth: | 11 | | 7 | | 2 |

logically this could be solved by c = b, b = a, a = x; cell = a & b & c.

however the result instead is nonsense.

code:

```
Sub getpingms_switch_Click()
Dim x As Integer: Dim y As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim p1 As String
Dim p2 As String
Dim p3 As String
Dim ms As String

p2 = "*"
p3 = "*"

For Each c In Sheets("Topology").UsedRange.Cells


    If c.Value = "Switch$" Then
        y = c.Column + 1: x = c.Row + 2
        DoEvents
        Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(x, y)) 'IsEmpty is a function that stops the Do Until when the cell is empty

            If Left(Cells(x, y), 7) = "172.21." Then

                ms = sPing(Cells(x, y)) 'sPing gets the ms of the pinged pc
                p3 = p2
                p2 = p1
                p1 = ms

                    Cells(x, y + 1) = p1 & " ms " & "| " & p2 & "ms | " & p3 & " ms"
                If p1 = "timeout" Then
                    Cells(x, y + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = "3"
                ElseIf p1 < 16 And p1 > -1 Then
                    Cells(x, y + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = "4"
                ElseIf p1 > 15 And p1 < 51 Then
                    Cells(x, y + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = "6"
                ElseIf p1 > 50 And p1 < 4000 Then
                    Cells(x, y + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = "45"
                Else
                    Cells(x, y + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = "15"
                End If
            End If
                x = x + 1

        Loop

    End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

technically I get the following result after the first run:

"   18 ms | ms | * ms"

"   1 ms |  18ms |  ms"

-

"   1 ms |  1ms |   18 ms"

"   24 ms |     1ms |   1 ms"

-

"   1 ms |  24ms |  1 ms"

"   1 ms |  1ms |   24 ms"

"   2 ms |  1ms |   1 ms"

-

"   2 ms |  2ms |   1 ms"

"   1 ms |  2ms |   2 ms"

-

"   1 ms |  1ms |   2 ms"

"   1 ms |  1ms |   1 ms"

-

"   1 ms |  1ms |   1 ms"

"   1 ms |  1ms |   1 ms"

"   1 ms |  1ms |   1 ms"

-

"   51 ms |     1ms |   1 ms"

"   1 ms |  51ms |  1 ms"

-

-

"   0 ms |  1ms |   51 ms"

"   0 ms |  0ms |   1 ms"

how could we fix this?

edit: I figured out why I get these results, but I can't find out how can this be solved.

Comment: Consider **Dimming** your string variables **above** the sub.  That way they will be *static* and retain their value from run to run.

Answer (score 1):

What you want are [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266296(v=vs.60).aspx) variables declared at the module scope. Static variables retain their value so long as the code is running.

```
Private Static variable As Integer

Private Sub Counter()
    variable = variable + 1
End Sub

Public Sub Main()
    Dim i as Integer
    For i = 0 To 10
        Counter
        MsgBox variable
    Next
End Sub
```

Each time you execute this code it will increment the variable counter.

Now, if you do not intend to run your function in a loop, and say, want to do this via button click instead, the static variable will lose it's value when the code has finished running. In that case, I would recommend storing the intermediate value in a hidden worksheet instead.

If you wanted to get *really* fancy, you could add a reference to Access and use a [TempVar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193475(v=office.15).aspx) to accomplish the same thing as well.

Comment: this is a good idea, I was thinking of storing it inside an array. I will try to get this working. Thanks for the idea!